# Running or sliding median, mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, mean, median

I am trying to calculate the running median, mean and std of a large array. I know how to calculate the running mean as below:

```
def running_mean(x, N):
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0))
    return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N)
```

This works very efficiently. But I do not quite understand why `(cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N)` can give the mean value (I borrowed from someome else).

I tried to add another return sentence to calculate the median, but it does not do what I want.

```
return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N), np.median(cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N])
```

Does anyone offer me some hint to approach this problem? Thank you very much.

Huanian Zhang

Comment: Is your goal to understand what's going on, or do you just want to use those functions? In the latter case you can find many of them predefined in `pandas` - see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments

Comment: `median` is an odd statistic.  It is just the middle value, or average to the 2 middle values.  That requires sorting the values, something quite different from summing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `cumsum` trick is specific to finding `sum` or `average` values and don't think you can extend it simply to get `median`  and `std` values. One approach to perform a generic `ufunc` operation in a sliding/running window on a `1D` array would be to create a series of 1D sliding windows-based indices stacked as a 2D array and then apply the `ufunc` along the stacking axis. For getting those indices, you can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Thus, for performing running mean, it would look like this -

```
idx = np.arange(N) + np.arange(len(x)-N+1)[:,None]
out = np.mean(x[idx],axis=1)
```

For running `median` and `std`, just replace [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with [`np.median`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) and [`np.std`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) respectively.

Comment: I tried your method, even though I do not quite understand how you did the sliding/running. But it gives some error. I put those two sentences under the definition of my running_mean, and return out, but it says "TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index". Could you explain that to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @HuanianZhang Let me ask you - Is `x` a 1D NumPy array and is `N` a scalar?

Comment: Probably my x is only a list, I need to transfer to 1D numpy array. Thank you very much.

Comment: Those two lines work very well for small np.array. But it always return some error for a huge array. I am dealing with an array of over 1 million elements.  I am trying to modify your code to avoid such errors, but I did not succeed. Would you offer me some ideas? Thank you very mcuh~

Comment: Thank you very much. I already fix it. It looks like I had some typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to estimate mean and standard deviation of a given sample set there exists incremental algorithms ([std](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102978/incremental-computation-of-standard-deviation), [mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing)) which helps you to keep the computational load low and do it online estimation. The computation of the median applies sorting. You can approximate the median. Let x(t) be your data at a given time t,m(t) the median of time t, m(t-1) the median value befor an e a small number e.g. e = 0.001 than

> m(t) = m(t-1) + e, if m(t-1) < x(t)
>
> m(t) = m(t-1) - e, if m(t-1) > x(t)
>
> m(t) = m(t), else

If you have a good inital guess of the median m(0) this works well. e should be choosen in relation to your values range and how many samples expect. E.g. if x = [-4 2 7.5 2], e = 0.05 would be good, if x = [1000 , 3153, -586, -29], e = 10.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce a wrapper to get moving "anything":

```py
import numpy as np

def runningFoo(operation):
    """ Make function that applies central running window operation
    """
    assert hasattr(np, operation), f"numpy has no method '{operation}'"

    method = getattr(np, operation)
    assert callable(method), f"numpy.{operation} is not callable"

    def closure(X, windowSize):
        assert windowSize % 2 == 1, "window size must be odd"
        assert windowSize <= len(X), "sequence must be longer than window"

        # setup index matrix
        half = windowSize // 2
        row = np.arange(windowSize) - half
        col = np.arange(len(X))
        index = row + col[:, None]

        # reflect boundaries
        row, col = np.triu_indices(half)
        upper = (row, half - 1 - col)
        index[upper] = np.abs(index[upper]) % len(X)
        lower = (len(X) - 1 - row, windowSize - 1 - upper[1])
        index[lower] = (len(X) - 2 - index[lower]) % len(X)

        return method(X[index], axis=1)

    return closure
```

For example, if you'd like to have running mean you may call `runningFoo("mean")`. Actually, you may call any appropriate method within NumPy. For example, `runningFoo("max")` will be a morphological dilation operation and `runningFoo("min")` will be a morphological erosion:

```py
runningStd = runningFoo("std")
runningStd(np.arange(10), windowSize=3)
```

Make sure that window size is odd. Also, please note that boundary points are reflected.