How to detect an object from image where the object and background have very similar colors?
I have an image where an object has very similar color to the background. I want to detect this object from the image and make the object white and the background should be black.

I have tried to think about a solution but I have not found one. I tried to convert to grayscale and then equalize histogram with cv2.equalizeHist, I tried to detect edges with cv2.Canny and I also tried to change HSV channels but I have no experience with that so I'm not sure if it helps or how I should do it. One thing that kind of makes the object a bit more visible, is CLAHE:
import cv2
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

def main():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5)
    cla = clahe.apply(gray)
    cv2.imshow("Image", cla)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

main()

But then again, I'm not sure how to continue the image processing from here so that I would be able to detect the object. How could I detect it?
EDIT:
@Christoph Rackwitz's answer is great, but I also found another way to kind of find the object with image processing methods. Here is the code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

def bilateral_filter(image):
    return cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 30, 75, 175)

def enhance_image(image, h_luminance, photo_render, block_size, search_window, gamma):
    denoised_image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image, None, h_luminance, photo_render, block_size, search_window)
    contrast_stretched_image = cv2.normalize(denoised_image, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]], np.float32)
    sharpened_image = cv2.filter2D(contrast_stretched_image, -1, kernel=kernel)
    improved_exposure = cv2.convertScaleAbs(sharpened_image, alpha=1, beta=5)
    lookup_table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** gamma) * 255 for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
    gamma_corrected_image = cv2.LUT(improved_exposure, lookup_table)
    return gamma_corrected_image

def convert_to_grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def black_and_white(image):
    return cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

def dilation(image, iter, ksize):
    kernel = np.ones((ksize, ksize), np.uint8)
    return cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=iter)

def erosion(image, iter, ksize):
    kernel = np.ones((ksize, ksize), np.uint8)
    return cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=iter)

def closing(image, ksize):
    kernel = np.ones((ksize, ksize), np.uint8)
    return cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

def sobel_filter(image):
    ddepth = cv2.CV_64F 
    ksize = cv2.FILTER_SCHARR 
    x = cv2.Sobel(image, ddepth, 1, 0, ksize=ksize, scale=1)
    y = cv2.Sobel(image, ddepth, 0, 1, ksize=ksize, scale=1)
    absx = cv2.convertScaleAbs(x)
    absy = cv2.convertScaleAbs(y)
    sobel_image = cv2.addWeighted(absx, 0.5, absy, 0.5, 0)
    return sobel_image

def use_clahe(grayscale_image, cliplimit):
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=cliplimit)
    cla = clahe.apply(grayscale_image)
    return cla

def process_image(image):
    contour_image = image.copy()
    sobel_image = sobel_filter(image)
    bilateral_image = bilateral_filter(sobel_image)
    h_luminance, photo_render, block_size, search_window, gamma = 7, 10, 6, 55, 5
    enhanced_image = enhance_image(bilateral_image, h_luminance, photo_render, block_size, search_window, gamma)
    grayscale_image = convert_to_grayscale(enhanced_image)
    clahe_process = use_clahe(grayscale_image, 20)
    thres = black_and_white(clahe_process)
    closed = closing(thres, 20)
    dilated = dilation(closed, 2, 2)
    eroded = erosion(dilated, 1, 4)
    processed_image = dilation(eroded, 2, 6)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(processed_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for contour in contours:
        cv2.drawContours(contour_image, [contour], -1, [0, 0, 255], 2)
    return processed_image, contour_image

def show_image(texts, images):
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        cv2.imshow("{}".format(texts[i]), image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    processed_image, contour_image = process_image(image)
    texts = ["Image 1: Original", "Image 2: Processed", "Image 3: Contours"]
    images = [image, processed_image, contour_image]
    show_image(texts, images)
    quit()

main()

The idea is to filter and enhance the image with filters and CLAHE. Then I apply morphological operations to the black and white image. However, this does not work perfectly and the contour is a bit offset as you can see: Result. So this is better than nothing and there is a lot of room to improve. I try to improve this code and also work on @Christoph Rackwitz's method and I will post more if I get better results.

I would recommend using a filter or kernel to pass over the image and make minor discrepancies (object borders) more numerically identifiable. Open CV has many of these filters built in. Here is an example of what I mean link

wouldn't call that an object but a "dent" in whatever surface you have there. depending on what you're content with, this can be easy to accomplish, or it can be a lot of effort. detecting the highlight and shadow of this dent is easy. they aren't connected though you can pair them up and connect them if you consider them a pair, indicating the same object.

I assume getting upper and lower limits based on the median might be able to solve this problem quite nicely....

@Tino D could you give a bit more details on what you mean?

Can you tell us how the desired output looks like? @programer I can come up with something

@programer. How about the object is blue and background to black?  Here is image https://ibb.co/YXZ1Wjj

@toyota Supra could you please add an answer where you explain how you managed to produce this image

My approach:

some blur to remove the Moire from the image
strong blur to estimate baseline
subtract
some thresholding
maybe (not) some morphological operations (open, dilate)
bounding box

On the Moire patterns, median blur is on par with gaussian or other lowpass. To make this dent go away, you best go with a median.
The tweakables are the blur radii and the standard deviation I'm using as a cutoff. I picked that "empirically", i.e. dialed it up until all the other noise from the picture died down. At 4, there's still other stuff.
In a real optical inspection application, you wouldn't divide by std() but pick a fixed threshold. Looking for 5-sigma stuff, relative to the picture itself, is bound to find something in every picture. That must be relative to a larger dataset.
im_u8 = cv.imread("I0klu.jpg")
im = im_u8 * np.float32(1/255)

background = cv.medianBlur(im_u8, 31) * np.float32(1/255)
background = cv.stackBlur(background, (11,11)) # median lets through some moire

blurred = im
blurred = cv.medianBlur(blurred, 5)
blurred = cv.stackBlur(blurred, ksize=(5,5))

show((blurred - background) * 10 + 0.5)


diff = blurred - background
diff /= diff.std()
mask = np.abs(diff) > 5
mask = mask.any(axis=-1)


bbox = cv.boundingRect(mask.astype(np.uint8))
(x, y, w, h) = bbox
pad = 10
bbox = (x-pad, y-pad, w+2*pad, h+2*pad)
canvas = im_u8.copy()
cv.rectangle(img=canvas, rec=bbox, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=1)



amazing answer as always!

eh, it works. state of the art is surely a neural network for segmentation. I'm also not happy that the median blur won't work on floats, at least not with a large kernel size. other libraries (skimage) might do it but *shrug*

NN can always work if you torture the data well enough, though not that great to melt a few icebergs for a SO answer

@Christoph Rackwitz Sorry for late reply, but this is an amazing answer, thank you! I try to proceed from here. Please check also the edited original post!

The image reminded me a bit of particle scans and I wrote something once to calculate primary and secondary profiles. Median filters can be used here to the benefit of removing noise, here's what I have as imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
def RunningMedian(x, N): # define the runningMedian filter
    '''
    Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71764962/16815358
    '''
    return median_filter(x[x != 0], N)
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("blue.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # read the image
r, g, b = cv2.split(im) # split to get the blue channel

In the following code, I do:

Going through each row in the blue channel
fit a parabola to detrend the data, this is what you were trying to do with CLAHE
Applying a running median on the data with 10 points, this is to smooth the data out a bit
Define the upper tolerance as the mean + 3 * std
Get the indices where the line is higher than that limit
Assign a 1 to that pixel in that row

The code is in a for loop and it should show you an animation if you are running on jupyter:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 1, 1]}, figsize = (3,6))
mask = np.zeros_like(b) # get a blank image for filling
for i in range(0,b.shape[0]-1):
    # calculations
    y = b[i,:] # get the row
    x = np.arange(len(y)) # defin the range
    coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 2) # find the coefficients
    polyFit = np.poly1d(coefficients) # define the polynomical function
    detrended = y - polyFit(x) # remove the trend
    detrendedMedian = np.abs(RunningMedian(detrended,10)) # get the median
    upperTolerance = np.mean(detrendedMedian)+3*np.std(detrendedMedian) # define upper tolerance as mu+3sigma
    idxTrue = np.where(detrendedMedian>upperTolerance) # get the pixels that exceed that limit
    mask[i,idxTrue] = 1 # assign true to those pixels
    # animation
    axs[0].cla() # clear plot for animation
    axs[1].cla() # clear plot for animation
    axs[2].cla() # clear plot for animation
    # plot the image with the current line
    axs[0].imshow(b) # show image
    axs[0].axhline(i, linewidth=5, color ="k") # line profiler
    # plot the profile
    axs[1].plot(detrendedMedian) # for the sake of this question, abs would be a better representation
    axs[1].axhline(upperTolerance, color = "r") # get the mean + 3*std
    axs[1].set_ylim((0,10)) # set the ylimit
    # plot the generated mask
    axs[2].imshow(mask)
    fig.canvas.draw() # update plot
    # plt.savefig("imagesForStack/"+str(i).zfill(5)+".png", dpi = 330) # save for gif

The animation itself will look like this:

At the end, you get a good enough mask that you can find contours on after a dilation or even opening:
maskDilated = cv2.dilate(mask, np.ones((5,5), dtype = np.uint8), iterations = 1) # dilate
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(maskDilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # find the contour
largestContour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea) # get largest contour by area
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largestContour) # get bounding box properties
imContoured = cv2.rectangle(im.copy(), (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 1) # draw rectangle
plt.figure() # create figure
plt.imshow(imContoured) # imshow the contoured image

The result:

Notice how the box is a bit bigger than it should be, here you should play a bit with the upper limit or maybe with morph operations to clean the mask.
If you tell me what exactly you want (maybe draw the desired results yourself as a bounding box and attach it to the post), I might be able to help you further.

Now that's a quality answer :)

Thanks! There's still some room for improvement... let's see what OP says

I want to detect this object from the image and make the object white and the background should be black

@toyotaSupra it's a nice to have, the big challenge is detecting the object. This can be solved as simple as cmap="gray"
